# What should I do if I pay for Oyster by credit card and forget to touch Oyster card after payment?

Tags: public-transport, london

I paid to top up my Oyster card by using a credit card and forgot to touch my Oyster card after payment. TFL has deducted money from my credit card, but my Oyster card doesn't have that money. What can I do?

Answer (score 8):

If you fail to tap your Oyster card after top up tfl should refund your money back to you credit card after 3 days.

I was going to link to the correct part of the tfl website but the oyster pages are unavailable due to maintenance today. (03.sept.14). But www.tfl.gov.uk

If you are worried you could phone the tfl helpline. 0343 222 1234.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Oyster Help site](https://custserv.tfl.gov.uk/icss_csip/SolutionDatabaseStart1.do?newTab=OYS), [this is what will happen](https://custserv.tfl.gov.uk/icss_csip/GetDetailInformation.do?entityNum=00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002949&kbname=SDB&src=searchSolution&newTabtext=Oyster):

> **What happens if I don't collect my online renewal/top up?**
>
> If you don't collect your online renewal, your order will be cancelled
>   and you will get a refund:
>
> • If you ordered a Travelcard, your order will be cancelled two days
>   after your chosen start date
>
> • If you topped up the pay as you go credit on your Oyster card, your
>   order will be cancelled seven days after your collection date
>
> Refunds will **not** be processed until at least four days after the
>   date your order was cancelled.
>
> You can check your Order History at [online](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/oyster) - Log into your
>   account and select the 'View Order History' link from the right hand
>   menu.
>
> Otherwise please contact the Oyster Helpline on 0343 222 1234 (open
>   08:00 - 20:00 daily)